# LIMIT in Postgres not supported in HQL?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I am having error using the following code in Grails executing HQL to get the first 30 Item objects:

```
 def items = Item.executeQuery('SELECT i FROM Item as i LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0')
```

my backend database is Postgres. However, I got:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column ...
```

Obviously, the error tells that LIMIT is not supported by HQL. How do I make it work? In other words, how do I make HQL execute native SQL that is well supported by Postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do it the [Grails/GORM way using list](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html) also

```
def items = Item.list(offset:0, max:30)
```

Since you are using HQL I have edited my answer based on comment below; either approach would work

```
def items = Item.executeQuery('SELECT i FROM Item as i', [max: 30, offset: 0])
```

Comment: better to use [max: 30, offset: 0] map as parameter as we talking about executeQuery method. Item.executeQuery('SELECT i FROM Item as i', [max: 30, offset: 0])

Answer (score 3):

```
query.setMaxResults(..)
```

Have a look at the [hibernate API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Query.html)