# Is this a good way to select the latest post?

Tags: sql, jpa, hql

I'm using a subselect to select the latest post. Is that a good idea?

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p INNER JOIN p.user WHERE p.user.username = :username AND p.updated = (SELECT MAX(p.updated) FROM Post p WHERE p.user.username = :username)")
Post findLatestByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

Comment: why not order by `Post` created date and updated date?

Comment: Because that returns more than one result.

Comment: limit your result to 1.

Comment: You can't do that with HQL.

Comment: Is `p.created` a date only or a datetime?

Comment: @toonice - It's a long.

Comment: Is the long used to represent a date or a date/time?

Comment: @toonice - My bad, I misread, it's unix ts.

Comment: What is the difference between `p.created` and `p.updated`?  If an older post has been updated after another was created (but not yet updated), should we select the older post or the newer post?

Comment: what DB do you use?

Comment: @Vecchiasignora - postgresql in production, h2 for testing. But I'd prefer that not to be reflected in the query.

Comment: ok , i will answer, just give me 5 minute

Comment: seems to be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708085/select-top-1-result-using-jpa

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to select latest row it using index descening

set `username, updated` columns as descening `index` if you dont have index on those columnes, for more information how to set it you can look link bellow

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createindex.html

then your select will be like this

```
SELECT * FROM Post p where p.user.username = :username LIMIT 1
```

your reading data will be already descening sortet after select, an then you can select 1 row and it will be latest row, data was decening sorted by `username`(and it is in where clause) and `updated` column

and about limit in HQL, you can solve this problem by other way
please  look links bellow

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhibernate-development/JYE3NDcTUEA

[How do you do a limit query in HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

[LIMIT in Postgres not supported in HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094610/limit-in-postgres-not-supported-in-hql/4094623)

Comment: 1. That is postgresql specific. 2. HQL doesn't feature limit.

Comment: is there any way to select 1 row?

Comment: Create a query which only returns one result.

Comment: look answer again, i attached 3 links about limit

Comment: That's not HQL.